# If statement isn't being read

Tags: java

This is how the if statement is written

```
            //Check and see if current is less than the next character.
            if (node.thisChar().charAt(0) < current.thisChar().charAt(0) )
            {
                temp = current;
                previous = node;
                node.next = current;

                System.out.println("Its in here");
                break;
            }// end if

            previous = current;
            current = current.next;

        //what was empty at the end of the list now has a new node being linked.

        System.out.println(current.thisChar().charAt(0) + " This is the current");
        System.out.println(node.thisChar().charAt(0) + " This is the new character");
        System.out.println("Character " + node.thisChar() + " has been added");
```

The issue's with that highlighted if statement. If for example a node letter `'d'` is less than current letter `'f'`, the if statement would end up being skipped, resulting in a unsorted list. The output placed within the if statement is never reached. What's odd is how my output would be showing the characters with `thisChar().CharAt()` (`thisChar` simply returns the character, and it's of type `String`) ; showing that the statements were working. Unless the issue lies with how the variables are of type `String`, I have no clue what is going on with the if statement. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: little problem and such huge code is posted

Comment: Your condition is true if "node" is less than "current". If you want it to *skip* in this case, you'll have to invert the condition.

Comment: Copy your three sysout statements to just before the if statement and see if you find anything helpful.

Comment: I do not understand your problem, because **charAt(X)** Returns the **char** value at the specified index **X**. (not return a String), so if you compare two char values, is the same as comparing two integer values. I think that the error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternate your comparing with the method

```
string.compareTo(String)
```

example

```
String s1, s2;
//blabla
//giving string variables values
s1.compareTo(s2)
```

See this [link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=207) for more information.

Comment: I assume you mean `compareTo` not `compare`

Comment: I'll see if this works, but it is in the same vein as what I've put in my if statement. My System.Out does accurately print out the letters entered, which makes me think that there's just something faulty with how the if statement takes the comparison. Hopefully this will work